# How to hide navbar when an image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I hide the navbar when an image is clicked?

[image: This is what it looks like]

[image: and I want it to be like this when an image is clicked]

This is the code for the image:

```
 <a href="gallery/1.png" class="fancybox" rel="ligthbox">
  <img src="gallery/1.png" class="zoom img-fluid">         
 </a>
```

I'm not gonna include the codes I tried because it's not clear and I'm not good in javascript.

Sorry for my bad English, Hope you understand it guys!

Comment: Show your code, show what you have tried so far. Nobody will be able to help with so little information.

Comment: Can you add the code? Kinda hard to help you with your code without it.

Comment: you can use `display:none` property to hide navbar on image click even and reset it to `display:block` on image close event.

Comment: Seems that you are using a **modal** for image, so make `z-index:999;` for the modal class.

Answer (score 3):

If your `button` class is `btn` and  `navigation bar` class is `navbar`

using JavaScript

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.onclick = function() {
    var navbar = document.querySelector('.navar');
    navbar.style.display = "none";
}
```

using jQuery

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.navar').hide();
});
```

Comment: It worksss! thank you so much man :) But which one is better? the jQuery or JS?

Comment: if you using `jQuery` in your project, use jQuery or use javascript

Comment: @Mhtyr If it works, please consider as an acceptable answer for the betterment of the community

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct in z-index of your navbar try to  reduce z-index value around `z-index:10`